# SQL Query to copy value of a meta_key into another meta_key

Tags: custom-field, sql

I am trying to figure out how to replace the value of one advanced custom field with the value from a different custom field. Would anyone be able to help me structure a SQL query that will do this across the database?

The meta_key that contains the material I am looking to duplicate is "ehp_citation", and the target of the duplication is "ehp_citation".

Comment: Are you _sure_ you want an SQL query? Let me put it this way - are you trying to do a one-time migration of old data, or are you looking to implement something programmatically (to work now and in the future)?

Comment: Good question - thanks for letting me clarify. Looking to do a one-time migration. The second step (which I think I know how to do) is to chop out some of the text in the targeted custom field.

Answer (score 3):

First take a db backup! 
Second, in your question you mention the same meta_key, so made the following assumption:

> The meta_key you want to keep is "ehp_citation"
>
> The meta_key you want to change is "ehp_citation_old" * so make the correction accordingly

Then you can try something like:

```
UPDATE `wp_postmeta` AS pm_to_change
LEFT JOIN `wp_postmeta` AS pm_we_want ON pm_to_change.post_id = pm_we_want.post_id
SET pm_to_change.meta_value = pm_we_want.meta_value
WHERE pm_to_change.meta_key = 'ehp_citation_old'
    AND pm_we_want.meta_key = 'ehp_citation'
    AND pm_we_want.meta_value != ''
```

also make sure you change the db prefix to mach yours.

To explain,

1) we say we want to update the `wp_postmeta` table and for reference we give it a name: `pm_to_change`

2) we make an LEFT JOIN to the same table (`wp_postmeta`) but this time we refer to it by: 'pm_we_want' and also we say that we want the data for the same `post_id`

3) here we say what to change. we want the `meta_value` of the `pm_to_change` to be SET to the `meta_value` of the `pm_we_want`

3) Finally we specify from which `meta_key` we want the above values. 
So we want the `meta_key` of the `pm_to_change` table to be: `ehp_citation_old` and the `meta_key` of the `pm_we_want` table to be: `ehp_citation`.

*Bonus 1*: The `AND pm_we_want.meta_value != ''` in the end also checks if the value we want, from `ehp_citation` is not empty. Which means that if it is empty, the we keep the old `ehp_citation_old`

*Bonus 2*: Run this SELECT first to check that we got the correct data:

```
SELECT pm_to_change.meta_value AS 'Change_This', pm_we_want.meta_value AS 'To_That'
FROM `wp_postmeta` AS pm_to_change
LEFT JOIN `wp_postmeta` AS pm_we_want ON pm_to_change.post_id = pm_we_want.post_id
WHERE pm_to_change.meta_key = 'ehp_citation_old'
    AND pm_we_want.meta_key = 'ehp_citation'
    AND pm_we_want.meta_value != ''
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to do this using Wordpress it's own function. You should consider looking into this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta / https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/

You could do a code that does the following

- Request all the posts/pages in which the posts that you need are loaded
- Loop through these items using a foreach loop or have_posts() function
- Within the posts, change the values for fields that you want to update.

Note that this is a work-around. It has worked for me many times, hope it works for you too.